# modify nested JSON array with JQ

Tags: json, edit, jq, any

I would like to use JQ to modify the following JSON input:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "value": "k1"
        },
        {
          "name": "val",
          "value": "2340378b211aa3d8f2d7607cbddce883b87b191d0425736641e3d308ea329718"
        },
        {
          "name": "Encoding",
          "value": "hex"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "value": "k2"
        },
        {
          "name": "val",
          "value": "2340378b211aa3d8f2d7607cbddce883b87b191d0425736641e3d308ea329718"
        },
        {
          "name": "Encoding",
          "value": "hex"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so that the `"hex"` value of the `"value"` field with name `"Encoding"` is modified to `"oct"` **only** for the row that contains a field with `.name=="id" and .value=="k1"`.

How would I do that? I can `select` a field with `.value=="k1"` etc. but I don't seem to be able to find a way to "go up the tree" to update the `"Encoding"` field subsequently.

The input cannot be expected to have a fixed field/row order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `any/2` yields a jq filter that closely matches the description of the problem in English:

```
.rows |= map( if any(.fields[]; .name=="id" and .value=="k1")
              then .fields |= map(if .name == "Encoding"
                                  then .value = "oct"
                                  else .
                                  end)
              else .
              end )
```

### Using when/2

A slightly less verbose and perhaps clearer solution is possible if we use a handy general-purpose function defined as follows:

```
def when(filter; action): if (filter?) // null then action else . end;
```

We can then write simply:

```
.rows[] |= when( any(.fields[]; .name=="id" and .value=="k1");
                 .fields |= map( when (.name == "Encoding";
                                       .value = "oct")))
```

### Caveats

- You might want to check whether .value == "hex" before changing it to "oct".
- The above filters could potentially change more than one name/value pair per "row".

Comment: I had a related problem: Selectively update a property in a nested array, using a parent property in the value generation. This answer helped in the right direction, so I refer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60073976/400068) where I answer my own question.